# Comparing two lists of different size and return bool-list

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, boolean

Let's say we have two lists:

Size(15)

```
list1 = [1012, 1017, 1037, 1057, ... , 1068]
```

Size(455)

```
list2 = [1029, 1049, 1012, 1117 ... , 1057]
```

How can I return a new list of Size(15) with boolean values if the item in list1 is in list2?
In list2 there are some items multiple times, in list1 every item appears just once.

Result should look like this: Size(15)

```
list_result = [True, False, False, True, ... , False]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a simple list comprehension. Since you have to use `in` `n` times, `n` being`len(list1)`, you can use a `set` to reduce the lookup complexity to `O(1)`, having then an overall complexity of `O(n)`:

```
list1 = [1012, 1017, 1037, 1057 , 1068]
set2 = set([1029, 1049, 1012, 1117,1057])

[i in set2 for i in list1]
# [True, False, False, True, False]
```